# DataAdapter Update() requires input parameter for Auto increment primary key column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado, parameters

While updating a DataTable to a SQL Server database I get the error message "Column 'PK_Column' does not allow nulls" after calling GetErrors()
I don't want to provide a value for PK_Column because it is a auto increment primary key column in the database. My insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Order] ([Customer_Id], [OrderTime], [OrderType])
VALUES(@Customer_Id, @OrderTime, @OrderType)
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int) AS '@PK_Column'
```

It works as expected in SQL Server Management Studio, so the query is obviously not the problem.

I have four parameters on the insert command, one output parameter (`@PK_Column`) and three input parameters `(@Customer_Id, @OrderTime, @OrderType)`. I figured out that I don't get the error if I set `@PK_Column` to InputOutput parameter, but then the `PK_Column` value does not get updated with the correct value created by the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT @PK_Column = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

This way, you assign to the local variable @PK_Column, which is picked up as a parameter.

When you do `... AS '@PK_Column'`, you are creating a data set with one column called "`@PK_Column`", when you want to assign a value to local var/parameter `@PK_Column`

Note: `... AS @PK_Column` would fail because this is column alias. You're relying on a setting that allows `'@PK_Column'` to be a valid alias where as `@PK_Column` would fail